# Angular 4 Drop Down Error With Simple Usage

Tags: angular, dropdown

I tried using the Angular 4 Drop Down:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-material-dropdown

Here is what I have as my div element:

```
<ng4-dropdown>
  <ng4-dropdown-menu>
    <ng4-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item }}
    </ng4-menu-item>
  </ng4-dropdown-menu>
</ng4-dropdown>
```

My items is contained in the corresponding typescript class and I have added the imports to the NgModule as below (my app.module.ts):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    Ng4DropdownModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    AuthGuard,
    JwtService,
    AuthenticationService,
    AlertService,
    ProfilesService,
    UserService,
    // providers used to create fake backend
    fakeBackendProvider,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I run my application, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setGlobalVar' of null
    at _createNgProbe (ng4-dropdown.bundle.js:6944)
    at eval (module.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at _callFactory (core.es5.js:9561)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.es5.js:9490)
    at initNgModule (core.es5.js:9441)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (core.es5.js:10555)
    at createNgModuleRef (core.es5.js:10539)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.es5.js:12833)
    at NgModuleFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (core.es5.js:13828)
    at core.es5.js:4497
```

This error seems to happen just by including the import to my NgModule, even without adding the div in my html component. Any ideas what this could be and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using wrong the component. Do you have the items defined in the component?
Anyway, you're referencing an undefined 'page' variable in the loop of items, try with item.

```
<ng4-dropdown-menu>
    <ng4-menu-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item }}
    </ng4-menu-item>
  </ng4-dropdown-menu>
</ng4-dropdown>
```

Comment: Nope! Still the same error! If you read my post carefully, I even do not have to add the div element to my HTML. Even just adding the imports to the NgModule produces this error!

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with webpack2. You can temporarily disable the disableDebugTools() from the webpack enviroments until you get a solution.

https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter/issues/263

Comment: Where do I disable this? What do you mean by temporarily disabling disableDebugTools()? If I disable this and want to make my application productive, will I have to re enable it?